# migrated system with new urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I am switching system from a MVC to a custom code system. Currently we are using this format for urls:

```
index.php?part=CAPACITOR&type=CERAMIC&model=0805&page=spec
```

I need now to rewrite urls like to be more nice for user like

```
mysitecom/CAPACITOR/
mysitecom/CAPACITOR/CERAMIC/
mysitecom/CAPACITOR/CERAMIC/0805/spec.html#2
```

where #1 and #2 are the pages loaded in jquery. The developer use the old way using /index.php/CAPACITOR/CERAMIC/0805/spec.html

Because I don't think using the index.php in the url is good, what can I do to make this better?

Comment: you are using apache? is mod-rewrite enable?

Comment: yes i think so, how can i check?

Comment: read this, let us know: http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what you need to use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ index.php?part=$1&type=all&model=all&page=index [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ index.php?part=$1&type=$2&model=all&page=index [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ index.php?part=$1&type=$2&model=$3&page=index [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_\.]+)\.html$ index.php?part=$1&type=$2&model=$3&page=$4 [L,NC]
```

So when a folder (example CERAMIC) is not provided you can add a flag to load all, same idea for model. It means that if only the first part is provided only he first rule will be used. As of the `page.html` by default you can load the index.

Now, `a-z0-9\-_` means any letters, numbers, dashes and underscore ONLY. You can use `([^/]+)` if you prefer that will allow you to use more characters.

The L mean `last` meaning if the rule match, it will stop. NC means non case so A = a or ABC = abc.